# Display css line horizontally on a material toolbar

Tags: css, angular-material, icons, toolbar

I want to put a horizontal icon sepation line on a "material toolbar" but it is always displayed vertically. here is the code :

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
    <a> <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/96/000000/link.png" class="logo" alt="logo" /></a>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <span flex></span>
    <div>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools menu">
            <a mat-button class="home"> <img
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/000000/cloud-network.png"></a>
            <a class="cp"> <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/000000/cloud-network.png"></a>
            <a mat-button class="p"> <img
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/000000/cloud-network.png"></a>
            <a mat-button class="cl"> <img
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/000000/cloud-network.png"></a>
             <div class="separation-line"></div> 
            <a mat-button class="mu"> <img
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/000000/cloud-network.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML has a built in horizontal rule tag (`<hr>`). You can learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp).